# JCR [JackRabbit] : Difference between Lock and Hold?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm trying to find out difference between Locks (JCR 2.0 Spec 17) and Hold (JCR 2.0 Spec 20). Unfortunately I do not get the point. What's the difference.

Thank you for any details!

Comment: Minor English standardization.

Comment: have you read up on "retention and hold management"?

Answer (score 0):

A lock is placed on a node by calling LockManager.lock (see §17.11.1 LockManager.lock). The node on which a lock is placed is called the holding node of that lock.

So if you place a deep lock on node1, node1 will hold the node, however any child nodes of node 1 will also be locked, *however they wont be holding the lock*

reference [§17.1 LockManager.lock](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/17_Locking.html)